# Cajas de color con tcolorbox en el cuaderno Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

No acabo de ver cómo puedo obtener una fórmula, dentro de una caja con un color de fondo, en un notebook de jupyter. Lo intento de la siguiente manera y no funciona correctamente. ¿Cuál es mi error?

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\begin{equation}
\tcboxmath[colback=magenta!25!white,colframe=magenta, title=Solución]
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k P{x_i}= 1}  
\end{equation}
```

Otra opción que he probado y tampoco me funciona es:

```
$$\fbox {{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k P{x_i}= 1}} $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente código

```
<div class="alert-success">
\begin{equation}
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k P{x_i}= 1}  
\end{equation}
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [answer]

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).